# Possible to get crash log if submit IPA to clients?

Tags: ios, ipa

I know we get crash log when distributing App with `TestFlight` and `App Store`. But is it possible to get crash log if binary is distributed as IPA, and Bundle ID belongs to our developer license?

[Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

[image]

Comment: you can add fabric crashlytics to your project. It will show you where/when/on which app crash.

Comment: Why? Apple provide the same.

Comment: Yes, but it is also a good option to get crash on each line with reason.